# Change label text between Core Animation repeating animation

Tags: ios, animation, uilabel, core-animation

I have made a `CAAnimation` (`CAAnimationGroup` to be precise) that scale and fade (opacity) from 0 -> 1 and then back 0 -> 1. The animation also repeats forever 
since I have set `animationGroup.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude`. This animation is applied to a `UILabel` and makes the label appear and disappear with a nice animation over and over.

I now want to change the text between each repetition of the animation (after it disappears but before it appears again). What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by removing the `animationGroup.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude` line and manually restarting the animation in the animation delegate method `animationDidStop(_:finished:)`. I also change the text of the label in the delegate method before restarting the animation. I'm not sure if this is the best solution though.